# Secret Variables in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure pipeline that needs to access a secret token to contact another service.  I've been following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables), but it does not seem to work as I'd expect.  As a minimal example, I'm trying to write the variable in `cachix_token` to a file.

```
  - bash: |
      set -ex
      mkdir -p packages
      echo $CACHIX_AUTH_TOKEN > packages/token
    env:
      CACHIX_AUTH_TOKEN: $(cachix_token)
```

However, when I download the resulting the token file, the contents are a literal

```
$(cachix_token)
```

How do I get yaml to substitute in the secret variable?

## Update

Below is a screenshot of where I've defined the secret variable for the pipeline.

[image]

Comment: How and where do you define this secret? Can you put a screenshot?

Comment: @MoonHorse  That's a good thought.  I've attached a screenshot from the Pipeline's variables page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I eventually found, Azure Pipelines doesn't allow forks to access secret variables.  So, even though the secret variable is defined for the pipeline, if you're performing a pull request off of a fork, instead of the main repo, then the secret variable is **not** defined and you'll see the behavior that I explained above.

As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#contributions-from-forks), this can be bypassed through the `Make secrets available to builds of forks` checkbox in the gui for the pipeline.  However, this does open a massive security hole where anyone can craft a malicious PR that gives them a verbatim copy of all your secrets.

Answer (score 1):

If you have literal`$(cachix_token)` in file it means that Azure Pipeline was not able to replace that variable. As this it means that you don't have it defined anywhere. You may also confirm this using this extension - [Print all variables](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.printAllVariables).

Here you have a documentation how to set [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables). However you can use also Azure Key Vault to store variables and then fetch values from it. Using built-in extension it also load them as secrets.

I repeat your steps:

```yaml
steps:
  - bash: |
      set -ex
      mkdir -p packages
      echo $CACHIX_AUTH_TOKEN > packages/token
      cat packages/token
    env:
      CACHIX_AUTH_TOKEN: $(cachix_token)
```

and got this:

```sh
+ mkdir -p packages
+ echo ***
+ cat packages/token
***
```

Which means that variable was correctly replaced.

Comment: I've included a screenshot above that, to my eyes, confirms that I have defined the variable.